# Indexing vectors and arrays with +:

Tags: system-verilog

I am seeing a code in SystemVerilog which has something like this:

```
if(address[2*pointer+:2])
  do_something;
```

How should I understand the `+:` when indexing this vector?

I found that it is called bit slicing, but I can't find an explanation about it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Description and examples can be found in [IEEE Std 1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 11.5.1 "Vector bit-select and part-select addressing". First IEEE appearance is IEEE 1364-2001 (Verilog) § 4.2.1 "Vector bit-select and part-select addressing". Here is an direct example from the LRM:

> ```
> logic [31: 0] a_vect;
> logic [0 :31] b_vect;
> logic [63: 0] dword;
> integer sel;
> a_vect[ 0 +: 8] // == a_vect[ 7 : 0]
> a_vect[15 -: 8] // == a_vect[15 : 8]
> b_vect[ 0 +: 8] // == b_vect[0 : 7]
> b_vect[15 -: 8] // == b_vect[8 :15]
> dword[8*sel +: 8] // variable part-select with fixed width
> ```

If `sel` is 0 then `dword[8*(0) +: 8] == dword[7:0]`
If `sel` is 7 then `dword[8*(7) +: 8] == dword[63:56]`

The value to the left always the starting index. The number to the right is the width and must be a positive constant. the `+` and `-` indicates to select the bits of a higher or lower index value then the starting index.

Assuming `address` is in little endian ([msb:lsb]) format, then `if(address[2*pointer+:2])` is the equivalent of `if({address[2*pointer+1],address[2*pointer]})`

Comment: So what would happen if we used a_vect[15 -: 32] ?

Comment: @umayneverknow I don't remember if the LRM mentioned what happens in take scenario. Should resolve/error the same as `a_vect[15 : -16]`. Try it and find out

Comment: Could not stop myself from commenting that `a_vect[ 0 +: 8]` and `b_vect[ 0 +: 8]` both resolve to `a_vect[7:0]` and `b_vect[7:0]` depending on the manner in which a_vect and b_vect were defined. Now that is **confusing** if you ask me

Answer (score 28):

This is another way to specify the range of the bit-vector.

x +: N,  The start position of the vector is given by x and you count *up* from x by N.

There is also

x -: N, in this case the start position is x and you count *down* from x by N.

N is a constant and x is an expression that can contain iterators.

It has a couple of benefits -

1. It makes the code more readable.
2. You can specify an iterator when referencing bit-slices without getting a "cannot have a non-constant value" error.

Comment: Thanks. But, what if we want to keep  both x and N as variables. How shall we implement it?

Comment: @vineeshvs can you provide an example?

Comment: I was thinking of keeping two loops with x and N as variables (say from 0 15 or something). But I think that's not allowed.