# Verilog: Better syntax for many cases in a case structure

Tags: syntax, case, verilog

I have a case structure in Verilog with approximately 95 cases.

```
        case(address)
            5'd0: header_buffer[7:0] <= writedata;
            5'd1: header_buffer[15:8] <= writedata;
            5'd2: header_buffer[23:16] <= writedata;
            5'd3: header_buffer[31:24] <= writedata;
```

As you can see, there is a very predictable pattern. Is there a better way to write this so that I don't have to manually write out all of the cases and so that I can scale it to an arbitrarily large size such as 100 or 200 cases? It seems like some type of for loop syntax would be very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done in one or two lines with bit slicing, however you need to check if your synthesizer property generates it.

```
header_buffer[8*address +: 8] <= writedata;
```

If the address could go out of range (ex address==100 and max is 95) then you should use if condition:

```
if (address < MAX_ADDRESS)
  header_buffer[8*address +: 8] <= writedata;
```

Description and examples can be found in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 11.5.1 *Vector bit-select and part-select addressing*. First IEEE appearance is IEEE 1364-2001 (Verilog) § 4.2.1 *Vector bit-select and part-select addressing*. You may also want to check out a previously answered question on [Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067571/indexing-vectors-and-arrays-with)

Word of caution. Despite the fact that bit slicing has been part of the standard since Verilog-2001, not all tools have fully implemented bit slicing with proper optimization. Some times a traditional full case statement will generate better results even though the two are functionally identical.