# How to initialize parameter array in verilog?

Tags: parameters, hex, verilog

How can one initialize parameter type array in verilog where each of members are 32 bit hexadecimal notation numbers?
I have tried the following but it gives me syntax error.

```
parameter [31:0] k[0:63] = {32'habc132, 32'hba324f, ...};
```

I'm using latest version of iverilog for compiling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameter array in Verilog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507629/parameter-array-in-verilog)

Comment: @Greg No, because this doesn't work.

Comment: Verilog-1995 doesn't support arrayed parameters. Verilog-2005 does but it the LRM is not explicit about multidimensional parameter arrays, it should support it. All version of SystemVerilog does support it, some require `'{}` to define the array.

Comment: @Greg You are correct. Seems like my compiler doesn't support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [EDA Plyground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Lu4) The following example works using modelsim 10.1, the file has a .sv extension, causing it to be interpreted as SystemVerilog:

```
module test;
parameter [31:0] k [0:1] = {32'habc132, 32'hba324f};

  initial begin
    $displayh(k[0]);
    $displayh(k[1]);
  end
endmodule
```

If setting to SystemVerilog does not work or is not available for your simulator I suggest including the syntax error in the question.