# Array of parameters in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog, questasim

I try to instantiate array of parameters, e.g.

```
module top();
    parameter array_size = 10;
    parameter par_array [array_size] = '{array_size{12}};

    initial begin
        $display("%d",par_array[array_size-1]);
    end
endmodule
```

But when I try to compile this module in questasim, I get this kind of error

> -- Compiling module top
>   ** Error: (vlog-13069) parameters_array.sv(3): near "[": syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ';' or ','.

Search on this subject led me to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507629/parameter-array-in-verilog) topic and answerer says that systemverilog does allow this kind of construction.
I really don't want use long parameter vector, cause it's lead to new difficulties and this construction is compiling in Vivado (but for the sake of verification I need to use Questa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameter arrays are only supported in `system verilog`. So, make sure that you compile in the system verilog mode (file extension .sv or whatever qualifiers you need).

Also you'd better do `int` in your case:

```
parameter int par_array [array_size] = '{array_size{12}};`
----------^^^
```

Comment: Yeah, I pretty sure, I'm using systemverilog (file extension is sv), and I've tried to use int.

Comment: well, it might not be implemented in questa. Talk to their support.

Comment: strange thing — I tried it again and it did work. Sorry for misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

An unpacked array parameter requires a data type.

```
parameter int par_array [array_size] = '{array_size{12}};
```

Only simple integral parameter can be specified without a data type and just a range.

Do yourself a favor and never rely on implicit data types anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define an dynamic array type some where:

```
typedef int int_arr_t[];
```

Then use the new define type in your module

```
module #(parameter array_size =12,
                  parameter int_arr_t par_array = '{array_size{12}})
```