# how to index a reg or memory in for-loop by for-variable?

Tags: for-loop, verilog

I have a problem with the code below. The code is synthesized in ISE 14.2.

```
input [1:8176] m_d_in;
reg [1:511] m_d [1:16];
integer i;

always @ (*)
  begin
    for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1)
       begin
         m_d[i+1] = m_d_in[ 1+511*i : 511+511*i];
       end
  end
```

after synthesizing, this error shows up:
HDL Compiler:1660_<'Address of CodeName.v> <'Line of Error>: procedural assignment to a non-register i is not permitted, left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar
the line of Error refer to this:

```
   m_d[i+1] = m_d_in[ 1+511*i : 511+511*i];
```

i also have tested using the:

```
reg [4:0] i;
```

and

```
genvar i;
```

instead of:

```
integer i;
```

and got exactly the same error I wrote above!
I know there is a solution by using a case instead of the code above, but in its not the right solution for me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are range is consistent, [Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067571/indexing-vectors-and-arrays-with/18068296#18068296) is also possible:

```
always @* begin
  for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1)
    m_d[i+1] = m_d_in[511*i+1 +: 511];
end
```

The indexed part select (`+:`/`-:`) and `generate` block (from Morgan's answer) were introduced in IEEE std 1364-2001. Any modern simulator and synthesizer will support them.

Answer (score 0):

If you use wire instead of reg then a single assign line can be wrapped up in a generate.

```
module tb(
input [1:8176] m_d_in
);
wire [1:511] m_d [1:16];

genvar i;

generate
  for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin
    assign m_d[i+1] = m_d_in[ 1+511*i : 511+511*i];
  end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

To keep the `reg` and use generates you would need to do:

```
module tb(
input [1:8176] m_d_in
);
reg[1:511] m_d [1:16];

 genvar i;

generate
  for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin
    always @* begin
      m_d[i+1] = m_d_in[ 1+511*i : 511+511*i];
    end
  end
endgenerate

endmodule
```