# Verilog: "... is not a constant"

Tags: verilog

I have three wires created like this:

```
wire [11:0] magnitude;
wire [3:0] bitsEnd;
wire [3:0] leadingBits;
```

All of them are `assign`ed some expression using combinational logic.  The following code works fine:

```
assign leadingBits[3] = magnitude[bitsEnd + 3];
assign leadingBits[2] = magnitude[bitsEnd + 2];
assign leadingBits[1] = magnitude[bitsEnd + 1];
assign leadingBits[0] = magnitude[bitsEnd + 0];
```

However, the following (seemingly equivalent) code gives the error `bitsEnd is not a constant`:

```
assign leadingBits[3:0] = magnitude[bitsEnd + 3:bitsEnd];
```

Can I not use shorthand for this assignment?  Why would this error be raised in the second case but not the first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Verilog you can't use a variable (i.e. `bitsEnd`) as the end of range. You can use `+:`/`-:` [operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067571/indexing-vectors-and-arrays-with) to solve your issue:

```
assign leadingBits = magnitude[bitsEnd+3 -: 4];
```

In the first case you only calculate single index (it's not a range). That's why the compiler is not complaining about it.