# Non-constant indexing for a logic statement in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to create a for loop that assigns different values to a logic array given the iteration of the loop.

So, for instance, let's say I am trying to instantiate two different bricks, both with a width of 10 and height of 5. Let's also say that each of these values are 10 bits. For two bricks, I have the code:

```
logic[19:0] Brick_Width;
logic[19:0] Brick_Height;
```

Where the first brick's width and height will be assigned into the most significant 10 bits and the second's in the least significant 10 bits.

This is the code that I currently have for this:

```
int i = 19;
initial
begin
 for(i=19; i>=0; i=i-10)
 begin
  assign Brick_Width[i:i-9] = 10;
  assign Brick_Height[i:i-9] = 5;
 end
end
```

However, I get an error saying that "i" is not a constant. Any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: You have two entities in your array (height and width), then it should be a two-dimensional array. i.e. logic [9:0] Brick_1 [5]

Comment: When you have logic[9:0] Brick_1 [5], does that mean there are 5 cells that each hold 10 bits?

Comment: Yes. There are 5 cells (depth is 5) and each holds 10 bit (width is 10).

Answer (score 9):

Commonly used range-select using `:` operator must have a **constant**. Your intent can be accomplished by what is known as **bit-select** operators.

Referring to example from [LRM 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section 11.5 as below:

```
logic [31: 0] a_vect;
logic [0 :31] b_vect;
logic [63: 0] dword;
integer sel;
a_vect[ 0 +: 8] // == a_vect[ 7 : 0]
a_vect[15 -: 8] // == a_vect[15 : 8]
b_vect[ 0 +: 8] // == b_vect[0 : 7]
b_vect[15 -: 8] // == b_vect[8 :15]
dword[8*sel +: 8] // variable part-select with fixed width
```

The `+:` and `-:` operators must be used for **bit-slicing or part select** as in your case. Here, you want to select a part from `i` to `i-9`, so the `-:` operator must be used. Like `Brick_Height[i-:9]=...`

For example,

```
x +: Y, the start position is x and count up from x by Y. Y is necessarily a constant.
x -: Y, the start position is x and count down from x by Y. Y is necessarily a constant.
```

One more thing, `assign` statement inside `initial` block, makes it **continuous procedural assignment**. The bit-select *won't work* in that case. To accomplish that, either simply **remove** `assign` **statement**. as follows:

```
for(i=19; i>=0; i=i-10)
 begin
    Brick_Width[i-:9] = 10; // no assign, rest all the stuff is same
    Brick_Height[i-:9] = 5;
 end
```

Or use a **generate block**, if **continuous driving** is the intent.

```
genvar i;
generate
for(i=19; i>=0; i=i-10)
begin
    assign Brick_Width[i-:9] = 10;
    assign Brick_Height[i-:9] = 5;
end
endgenerate
```

More information on bit-select can be found at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067571/indexing-vectors-and-arrays-with) link.

**SIDE NOTE:**

Referring to following phrase in your question:

> For two bricks, I have the following code:

You must have an **array** like `logic[9:0] Brick [2]`.