# Malformed statement Verilog

Tags: verilog

```
module myfunction();
    function [31:0] myfunction;
            input [31:0] a;
            localparam bytes = 4;
            begin
              for(i=0; i<4;i= i+1)
              begin
                myfunction[8*i + 7: 8*i] = input[(3 - i*8) + 7 :   (3 -i)*8];
              end
    endfunction
endmodule
```

I am getting error of malformed statement on line myfunction in for loop. I am very new to verilog. Please help me with the error

Comment: Post the exact error message, please.

Comment: I did that and the error has gone. I am getting a new error as follows: i is not constant on line myfunction in for loop

Answer (score 2):

As @alex.forencich showed, **bit-slicing** is to be done by `+:` operator since you have non-constant slicing index.

Also, `input` is a **SystemVerilog keyword**. So, change of variable name is required here. `i` needs to be declared. The following snippet is compiled version of your code.

```
module myfunction_mod();
    function [31:0] myfunction;
            input [31:0] a;
           // Dummy input1 declared for sample
            reg [31:0] input1;
            localparam bytes = 4;
            begin
              for(int i=0; i<4;i= i+1) // declare i
              begin
               // Note input1 here
               myfunction[8*i +: 8] = input1[8*(3-i) +: 8];
               // Else use a here
               // myfunction[8*i +: 8] = a[8*(3-i) +: 8];
              end
            end
    endfunction
endmodule
```

This shall solve the compile error. One more comment from my side, keep **different function name and module name** as far as possible. This shall help in hierarchy issues.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864574/non-constant-indexing-for-a-logic-statement-in-systemverilog/33865519) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067571/indexing-vectors-and-arrays-with) links for bit-slicing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what error you're getting here.  However, I would recommend using the indexed part select style like so:

```
myfunction[8*i +: 8] = input[8*(3-i) +: 8]
```

You should also make sure all of your begins and ends are matched up.

Comment: I did that and the error has gone. I am getting a new error as follows:
i is not constant on line myfunction in for loop.

Comment: You might need to define i locally as well.