# Method of instantiating sequential block in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to instantiate sequential counter block in another module. These are the following modules. When I synthesize these modules in synopsys design vision environment it provides the following error message,

> prob_calculator.sv:1: Illegal reference to memory prob. (VER-253)

```
module counter #(parameter m=16) (input en,input clk,input reset,output reg [m-1:0] out);

always @(posedge clk)
if(reset) begin
    out <= 0;
end
else if (en) begin
    out <= out+1;
end
endmodule
```

Instantiation of the counter block:

```
module prob_calculator #(parameter n=32,parameter m=6,parameter Ir=14) (input
[n-1:0]b,input clk,input reset,output reg [m-1:0] prob [0:Ir-1]);

genvar i;
generate
for (i=0;i<Ir;i=i+1) begin:x1
counter #(.m(m)) count_blck(.en(1),.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.out(prob[i]));
end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

Can anyone please point out what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog does not support multi-dimensional arrays through ports. SystemVerilog does support multi-dimensional array ports. However, not all SystemVerilog synthesizers support this feature.

Before addressing how to get around the multi-dimensional port constraint, I want to point out that `probe` should be declared as a `wire` not a `reg`. In Verilog, a variable should be declared as a `reg` when it is assigned by an procedural block (i.e. `always` or `initial`) in the current module (not its sub-module or parent module), otherwise it should be declared as a `wire`. With SystemVerilog you could also use `logic` and may use the `logic` type more liberally; all places where you use `reg` and most places where you use `wire` (exclude `wires` that have multiple drives).

If you change `probe` from `reg` to `wire` it may make your synthesizer happy, but it probably won't.

One way is to flatten `prob` into a single vector: change `output reg [m-1:0] prob [0:Ir-1]` to `output wire [Ir*m-1:0] prob`. Then change the connections between out and probe into an slice of new prob vector: `.out(prob[i])` to `.out(prob[i*m +: m])` (See [Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732)). This approach is works with SystemVerilog and Verilog (IEEE1364-2001 and above).

```
module prob_calculator #(parameter n=32,parameter m=6,parameter Ir=14) (input
[n-1:0]b,input clk,input reset,output wire [Ir*m-1:0] prob);

  genvar i;
  generate
    for (i=0;i<Ir;i=i+1) begin:x1
      counter #(.m(m)) count_blck(.en(1),.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.out(prob[i*m +: m]));
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

SystemVerilog offers other possibilities such as using (`typedef`, packed `struct`, `interface`, `modport`) that may work as work around if multi-dimensional port are not directly supported. It is best to refer to your synthesizer's manual, ensure the SystemVerilog option is enabled and check for what features are/are-not supported.

---

<sub>FYI: With SystemVerilog its recommenced to use `always_ff@(posedge clk)` instead of `always@(posedge clk)`</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Flattening `prob` variable works.
I will look into other possibilities you have mentioned.