# Convert vector into array

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have a vector like this

```
wire [N:0] Vector[M:0];
```

and I want to convert it into an array of size M*N. A pseudocode could be:

```
Array={Vector[M],Vector[M-1],Vector[M-2],...,Vector[0]}
```

So I want to concatenate the elements of the vector in an array.
I tried to do it using a loop, but when I try to simulate it gives a fatal error without description. Is there a simpler way of doing it? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I guessing you tried something like this: `Array[N*(index+1) : N*index ] = Vector[index];` in an always block. This will not work because Verilog requires both sides of the range to be constants (during simulation).

There are three Verilog approaches to get the desired assignment:

1. Bit assignment
2. Array slice assignment
3. Generate loop assignment

**Bit assignment**
In Verilog-95 (IEEE1364-1995), the only ways achieve this was bit assignments with a double for-loop:
`Array[N*index_m+index_n] = Vector[index_m][index_n];`

```
reg [M*N:0] Array;
integer index_m, index_n;
always @(Vector) begin // Verilog-95 style sensitivity list
  for(index_m=0; index_m <= M; index_m = index_m + 1) begin
    for(index_n=0; index_n <= N; index_n = index_n + 1) begin
      Array[N*index_m+index_n] = Vector[index_m][index_n];
end
endgenerate
```

**Array slice assignment**
Another approach is vector slicing with `+:` (A feature added in IEEE1364-2001. Refer to [Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732)). This allows one variable starting index and a constant offset for the range.
`Array[N*index +: N ] = Vector[index];`

```
reg [M*N:0] Array;
integer index;
always @* begin // Verilog-2001 style sensitivity list
  for(index=0; index <= M; index = index + 1) begin
    Array[index*N +: N ] = Vector[index];
end
endgenerate
```

**Generate loop assignment**
A third approach would be to use a `generate` block (also added in IEEE1364-2001). A generate blocks for-loop unravels at elaboration. There form you could use `Array[N*(index+1) : N*index ] = Vector[index];`, provided that `index` is a `genvar`:
Or with a generate block

```
wire [M*N:0] Array; // note 'wire'
generate
genvar g_index; // The 'g_' prefix is suggested coding style to identified genvars
for(g_index=0; g_index <= M; g_index = g_index + 1) begin
  assign Array[(g_index+1)*N] : g_index*N] = Vector[g_index];
  //assign Array[g_index*N +: N ] = Vector[g_index]; // +: also works
end
endgenerate
```

SytemVerilog ([IEEE1800](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html)) added bit streaming which can do the operation in one step `Array = {>>{Vector}};`, but I am unaware how common it is supported for synthesis. (I typically use array slicing (`+:`) with SystemVerilog's `foreach` in an `always_comb`)