# How to use the input's values in "always" definiton in Verilog

Tags: verilog, quartus

I got the problem with using the input's value in Verilog.
I write:

```
module reg_vector (INPUT, ICLK, IENBL, NR, OUT);
parameter k = 6;
parameter n = 3;
input [(8*k)-1:0] INPUT;
input ICLK;
input IENBL;
input [n-1:0] NR;

reg [n-1:0] temp;
output reg [7:0] OUT;

always@ (temp, posedge ICLK)
begin
    if (IENBL)
        begin
            OUT = INPUT[temp*8 : temp*8+8];
        end
end

endmodule
```

But got the error:

> Error (10734): Verilog HDL error at reg_vector.v(25): temp is not a
>   constant

How should I fix it?
Thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INPUT[temp*8 : temp*8+8]` does not work because the `:` range syntax requires both sides to be a constant.
What you want is to use the `+:` array slicing: `INPUT[temp*8 +: 8]`
The left hand side of `+:` allows variables and represents the starting index. The right hand side is the width and must be a constant. For more on `+:` see [Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732)

Other issues:

1. Remove `temp` from the sensitivity list.
2. `temp` needs to be assigned to something
3. `OUT` should be assigned with non-blocking (`<=`) not blocking (`=`) since it is sequential logic.

```
always @(posedge ICLK) // no temp in sensitivity list
begin
  if (IENBL)
  begin
    OUT <= INPUT[temp*8 +: 8]; // non-blocking and +:
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your vector is always 1 byte wide, the tool understands it as a variable size and it does not know how to deal with it. (you also inverted the indexes `temp*8` and `temp*8+8` in the vector selection)

Another way to do it is to use the shift operator

```
OUT = INPUT >> (temp*8);
```

This should work as `OUT` will take the lower 8bits of the shifting by `8*temp` of `INPUT`

Comment: Well, the error has gone, but i am not sure that the shift operator is solution. 
I need to connect the input legs with the output, depends on the NR input.
I mean if the NR = 0
OUT = IN[7:0]
And if NR = 1
OUT = IN[15:8]