# binding parameter to array value error (Verilog)

Tags: arrays, verilog, fpga

I'm trying to initialize an array of modules, and they each have 3 parameters, 2 of which are based on values that I define in a pair of reg packed arrays at the top of the module like this:

```
reg[31:0] k [0:63] = '{
32'hd76aa478, 32'he8c7b756, 32'h242070db, 32'hc1bdceee,
32'hf57c0faf, 32'h4787c62a, 32'ha8304613, 32'hfd469501,
32'h698098d8, 32'h8b44f7af, 32'hffff5bb1, 32'h895cd7be,
32'h6b901122, 32'hfd987193, 32'ha679438e, 32'h49b40821,
32'hf61e2562, 32'hc040b340, 32'h265e5a51, 32'he9b6c7aa,
32'hd62f105d, 32'h02441453, 32'hd8a1e681, 32'he7d3fbc8,
32'h21e1cde6, 32'hc33707d6, 32'hf4d50d87, 32'h455a14ed,
32'ha9e3e905, 32'hfcefa3f8, 32'h676f02d9, 32'h8d2a4c8a,
32'hfffa3942, 32'h8771f681, 32'h6d9d6122, 32'hfde5380c,
32'ha4beea44, 32'h4bdecfa9, 32'hf6bb4b60, 32'hbebfbc70,
32'h289b7ec6, 32'heaa127fa, 32'hd4ef3085, 32'h04881d05,
32'hd9d4d039, 32'he6db99e5, 32'h1fa27cf8, 32'hc4ac5665,
32'hf4292244, 32'h432aff97, 32'hab9423a7, 32'hfc93a039,
32'h655b59c3, 32'h8f0ccc92, 32'hffeff47d, 32'h85845dd1,
32'h6fa87e4f, 32'hfe2ce6e0, 32'ha3014314, 32'h4e0811a1,
32'hf7537e82, 32'hbd3af235, 32'h2ad7d2bb, 32'heb86d391
};
```

and

```
reg[4:0] s [0:63] = '{
7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,
5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,
4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,
6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21
};
```

I'm accessing those values when instantiating the modules like this:

```
hash_op #(0,s[0],k[0]) hash_op_0( // <- ERROR HERE!
    .clk(clk),
    .a(a_initial),
    .b(b_initial),
    .c(c_initial),
    .d(d_initial),
    .m(message_padded),
    .a_out(bl_a[1]),
    .b_out(bl_b[1]),
    .c_out(bl_c[1]),
    .d_out(bl_d[1]),
    .m_out(bl_m[1])
    );

generate
    genvar i;
        for(i = 1; i<64; i=i+1)
        begin : generate_hash_ops
            hash_op #(i,s[i],k[i]) hash_op_i( // <- ERROR HERE!
                .clk(clk),
                .a(bl_a[i]),
                .b(bl_b[i]),
                .c(bl_c[i]),
                .d(bl_d[i]),
                .m(bl_m[i]),
                .a_out(bl_a[i+1]),
                .b_out(bl_b[i+1]),
                .c_out(bl_c[i+1]),
                .d_out(bl_d[i+1]),
                .m_out(bl_m[i+1])
                );
        end
endgenerate
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
λ iverilog -o test -c file_list.txt
md5-core.v:49: error: Unable to bind parameter `k['sd0]' in `md5core'
md5-core.v:49: error: Unable to bind parameter `s['sd0]' in `md5core'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[1]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[1]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[2]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[2]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[3]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[3]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[4]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[4]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[5]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[5]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[6]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[6]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[7]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[7]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[8]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[8]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[9]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[9]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[10]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[10]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[11]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[11]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[12]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[12]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[13]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[13]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[14]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[14]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[15]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[15]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[16]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[16]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[17]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[17]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[18]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[18]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[19]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[19]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[20]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[20]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[21]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[21]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[22]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[22]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[23]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[23]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[24]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[24]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[25]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[25]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[26]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[26]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[27]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[27]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[28]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[28]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[29]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[29]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[30]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[30]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[31]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[31]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[32]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[32]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[33]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[33]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[34]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[34]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[35]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[35]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[36]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[36]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[37]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[37]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[38]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[38]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[39]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[39]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[40]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[40]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[41]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[41]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[42]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[42]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[43]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[43]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[44]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[44]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[45]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[45]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[46]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[46]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[47]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[47]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[48]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[48]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[49]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[49]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[50]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[50]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[51]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[51]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[52]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[52]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[53]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[53]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[54]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[54]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[55]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[55]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[56]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[56]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[57]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[57]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[58]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[58]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[59]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[59]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[60]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[60]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[61]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[61]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[62]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[62]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `k[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[63]'
md5-core.v:67: error: Unable to bind parameter `s[i]' in `md5core.generate_hash_ops[63]'
128 error(s) during elaboration.
```

Does anyone have any advice? I might be initializing the arrays wrong, or maybe verilog just doesn't support defining parameters based on array values, but I doubt that. Is there a more resource efficient to define my parameters? I don't ever use the values in these arrays beyond this generate sequence. "k" can be defined by a function instead, which I might use, but s cannot be.

Comment: Trie changing the `reg` to `parameter` when defining `s` & `k`. You may need to enable SystemVerilog

Comment: @Greg thanks! switching it to a parameter worked, but now I'm stuck using modelsim because icarus verilog doesn't fully support systemverilog yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k` and `s` need to be defined as parameters to compile. Easiest solution is to change `reg` to `parameter` and enable SystemVerilog. Verilog does not support unpacked parameter arrays or the unpacked arrays syntax `'{}`. To make it Verilog complement you need to change `k` and `s` into a a single packed arrays (aka a vector).

`k` is a relatively easy change: `reg [31:0] k [0:63] = '{` --> `parameter [32*64-1:0] k = {`

`s` is similar but you need to prefix 5'd to all the entries it will pack correctly (otherwise verilog will treat `7` as `32'd7`)

```
parameter [64*5-1:0] s = {
5'd7, 5'd12, 5'd17, 5'd22,  5'd7, 5'd12, 5'd17, 5'd22,  5'd7, 5'd12, 5'd17, 5'd22,  5'd7, 5'd12, 5'd17, 5'd22,
5'd5,  5'd9, 5'd14, 5'd20,  5'd5,  5'd9, 5'd14, 5'd20,  5'd5,  5'd9, 5'd14, 5'd20,  5'd5,  5'd9, 5'd14, 5'd20,
5'd4, 5'd11, 5'd16, 5'd23,  5'd4, 5'd11, 5'd16, 5'd23,  5'd4, 5'd11, 5'd16, 5'd23,  5'd4, 5'd11, 5'd16, 5'd23,
5'd6, 5'd10, 5'd15, 5'd21,  5'd6, 5'd10, 5'd15, 5'd21,  5'd6, 5'd10, 5'd15, 5'd21,  5'd6, 5'd10, 5'd15, 5'd21
};
```

The order of the indexing is not reversed. The old `k[0]` is now `k[64*32-1 : 63*32]`. Since the looping is being done with constants and genvars, you can do `k[(64-i)*32-1 : (63-i)*32]`.

```
hash_op #(0,s[64*5-1 : 63*5],k[64*32-1 : 63*32]) hash_op_0(
...

for(i = 1; i<64; i=i+1) begin : generate_hash_ops
  hash_op #(i,s[(64-i)*5-1 : (63-i)*5],k[(64-i)*32-1 : (63-i)*32]) hash_op_i(
  ...
```

I prefer [indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068296/1959732) so the mathematical expression used to calculate the index is only one side, plus using `+:` works with variable and net types within always blocks and assign statements, and it is less typing.

```
hash_op #(0,s[63*5 +: 5],k[63*32 +: 32]) hash_op_0(
...

for(i = 1; i<64; i=i+1) begin : generate_hash_ops
  hash_op #(i,s[(63-i)*5 +: 5],k[(63-i)*32 +: 32]) hash_op_i(
  ...
```

This strategy does work on icarus verilog 0.10. I looks like icarus verilog 0.9.7 and old has a limitation that it can only use the whole value of a parameter; it gives the message "*sorry: Cannot part select bits of parameters.*"
This strategy does work with modelsim and should work with any simulator that is compliant with IEEE1364-2001 or IEEE1800