# how to concatenate a row buffer into a register in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a problem with this

```
wire [7:0] table [0:999];
wire [8*1000-1:0] y;

assign y = {table[0], table[1], table[2], ...., table[999]}; // this line code is right, I don't want hard code
```

I want y is all 1000 values of table but I don't know how to assign all values in 1 line of code( or 2,3). code assign above is right but if there is 100000 values, do I have to type 100000 times?

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after the closing brace.

Comment: yeah.  I know. Do you know the faster way? I don't want to type 1000 times,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop but your problem is the sensitivity list. Not all simulators allow two dimensional arrays as sensitivity argument.

```
wire [7:0] tbl [0:999];
reg  [8*1000-1:0] y; // <<== Needs to be reg 

integer i;

always @( tbl ) // <<== may give error/warning
    for (i=0; i<1000; i=i+1)
        y[i*8 +: 8] = tbl[i];
```

Comment: Nope `[i*8+8-1:i*8]` is illegal unless `i` is a genvar. Also `++` is not supported in Verilog (it is in SystemVerilog)

Comment: Yes, I was writing some C code. Also y must be reg and 'table' is a reserved word. The above passed my Verilog syntax checker.

Comment: @Greg there is no genblock around, why genvar then? `+:` might not work though in verilog.

Comment: @oldfart Generate was added in Verilog-2001; so was `+:`/`-:`. A generate solution would look like: `genvar i; generate for(i=0;i<1000;i=i+1) begin assign y[i*8+8-1:i*8] = table[i]; end endgenerate` It works, but I find the `+:` is usually a cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using Verilog-2001 or higher, you can use:

```
wire [7:0] table [0:999];
reg [8*1000-1:0] y;
integer i;
always @* begin
  for (i=0; i<1000; i=i+1) begin
    y[ i*8 +: 8] = table[i];
  end
end
```

See: [Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732)

Verilog-95 solution is not as pretty and has more overhead:

```
wire [7:0] table [0:999];
reg [8*1000-1:0] y;
integer i;
always @( table ) begin
  y = {8000{1'b0}};
  for (i=999; i>=0; i=i-1) begin
    y = {[8*999-1:0],table[i]};
  end
end
```

---

If you can use SystemVerilog, it can be done in one step with bitsteaming

```
wire [7:0] table [1000];
wire [8*1000-1:0] y = {<<8{table}};
```