# how implement store byte and store half-word in realistic approach

Tags: verilog, mips, system-verilog, cpu-architecture

i'm implementing an instance of single cycle MIPS processor. i want to implement store half-word and store byte

I've added a new input signal to my "Data memory" to control what to store like the code below.

```
// this was prof. Harris implementation in "digital design and computer 
// architecture book" implementation before i turn the "we" (Write Enable) signal into 2 bits  

module dmem(input logic clk, [1:0]we, //where we is an output of the control unit
            input logic [31:0] a, wd, 
            output logic [31:0] rd);

logic [31:0] RAM[63:0];

assign rd = RAM[a[31:2]]; // word aligned

always_ff @(posedge clk)
    case(we)
        2'b01: RAM[a[31:2]] <= wd; // sw 
        2'b10: RAM[a[31:0]][15:0] <= wd[15:0]; // sh
        2'b11: RAM[a[31:0]][7:0] <= wd[7:0]; // sb
        default:
        // do nothing
        ...
```

is this realistic if it's not what is the conventional way to implement it?

I'm studying it as a hobby, sorry if my question seems to be stupid

Comment: No, that does not work. To be honest, it is a big mess. You should not ask us *"if it is  realistic or not"* The normal way to find out is to write a test-bench and test your code. Just one tip: For 32 bits data and byte write enable you normally have 4 enable lines.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that enable normally has 4 lines

Comment: where can i find the normal standards? because i don't know what to google exactly

Comment: It is not an official standard, but of you look up the most uses buses e.g. AXI you find they all have a byte-write-enable for each byte lane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main index for the RAM must always be the word address. I am assuming half-word write can upper and lower portions of the word, and byte write can assign to any byte within the word.

You can use the `+:` slice operator (See [Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732)) to assign a portion of the word

```
always @(posedge clk) // NOTE: always_ff is SystemVerilog
  case(we)
    2'b01: RAM[a[31:2]] <= wd; // sw 
    2'b10: RAM[a[31:2]][ {a[1],4'b0000} +: 16] <= wd[15:0]; // sh
    2'b11: RAM[a[31:2]][ {a[1:0],3'b000} +: 8] <= wd[7:0]; // sb
    default:
    // do nothing
  endcase
```

With SystemVerilog, there is also the option of multi-dimensional packed arrays

```
//    [shw][sby][dat]    [sw  ]
logic [1:0][1:0][7:0] RAM[63:0];

assign rd = RAM[a[31:2]]; // word aligned

always_ff @(posedge clk)
  case(we)
    2'b01: RAM[a[31:2]] <= wd; // sw 
    2'b10: RAM[a[31:2]][a[1]] <= wd[15:0]; // sh
    2'b11: RAM[a[31:2]][a[1]][a[0]] <= wd[7:0]; // sb
    default:
    // do nothing
  endcase
```

I don't know how well most synthesizers will treat multi-dimensional packed arrays. Any synthesizer compatible with IEEE1364-2001 or latter will support `+:`, however I have seen mix results in how efficient the results are compared nested case statements. You will need to experiment.

Answer (score 3):

Your RAM is using word addresses, no?  I say this b/c the elements are word sized.

Thus, we have to use a word address to index them, so you'll have to use a[31:2] for all store types, not just `sw`.

The store half (`sh`) then will go to RAM[a[31:2]] [15:0] if the a[1] is even/0, and [31:16] if a[1] is odd/1.  (Assuming little endian — swap these if big endian.)

The store byte will go to RAM[a[31:2]] [7:0] if a[1:0] is 2'b00, [15:8] if 2'b01, [23:16] if 2'b10, and [31:24] if 2'b11.

---

Alternatively, you can model RAM using bytes, and then the `sb` will be trivial, while the `sh` and `sw` will be more complex: `sw` will require updating 4 different location in RAM, since they are bytes in this scheme.