# How to access multidimensional array in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

What is the meaning of this statement? Well, I am trying to understand to access this memory.

```
mem[addr_i][i*DataBitsPerMask +: DataBitsPerMask]
```

Comment: if (write_i) begin
        for (int i=0; i < MaskWidth; i = i + 1) begin
          if (wmask[i]) begin
            mem[addr_i][i*DataBitsPerMask +: DataBitsPerMask] <= wdata_i[i*DataBitsPerMask +: DataBitsPerMask];
          end
        end

Comment: I think you need to understand `+:` and the rest will make sense. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732

Comment: Yes got it thanks.